# Django - Update page for a model with one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django app, where I have Post and PostImage models.

Each Post has multiple PostImages.

In the Post add page, I have forms for both Post and PostImages. I have used formset for PostImages. Here's the code for views:

```
def post_new(request, template_name="posts/new.html"):


  post_form = Post(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
  PostImageFormSet = formset_factory(PostImageForm, extra=1)
  post_image_formset = PostImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, prefix='post_images')

  if post_form.is_valid() and post_image_formset.is_valid():
    post = post_form.save(commit=False)
    post.save()
    for post_image_form in post_image_formset:
      post_image = post_image_form.save(commit=False)
      post_image.post = post
      post_image.save()

    redirect_url = urlresolvers.reverse('post_show')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

  form_data = {'post_form': post_form, 'post_image_formset': post_image_formset}
  csrfContext = RequestContext(request, form_data)
  return render_to_response(template_name, csrfContext)
```

I use jQuery to add more forms for PostImage, and it works perfectly fine, I am able to create a post with as many images as I want.

Now, I want my post_edit page to work in a similar way. Here's my code for the post_edit view method:

```
def post_edit(request, post_slug, template_name="developers/posts/edit.html"):
  post = get_object_or_404(post, slug=post_slug)
  post_images = PostImage.objects.filter(post_id=post.id)
  count = len(post_images)
  post_form = postForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)
  postImageFormSet = formset_factory(postImageForm, extra=count)
  post_image_formset = postImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, prefix='post_images')

  for post_image_form, post_image in zip(post_image_formset.forms, post_images):
    post_image_form.initial = post_image
  if post_form.is_valid():
    post_form.save()
    redirect_url = urlresolvers.reverse('developer_post_show', args=[post_slug])
    return redirect(redirect_url)

  form_data = {'post_form': post_form, 'post_image_formset': post_image_formset}
  csrfContext = RequestContext(request, form_data)
  return render_to_response(template_name, csrfContext)
```

Here's my template for edit page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load thumbnail %}

  {% if error_message %} <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p> {% endif %}
  {{ post_form.errors }}
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div>
        ... Post related HTML
      </div>

      <div class="post-images" style="clear: both;">
        {% for post_image_form in post_image_formset %}
          <div>
            {{ post_image_form.caption  }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>

      <div style="clear: both; position: relative; left: 320px;">
        <input type="submit" value = "Update post" />
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I get the error in my template saying:

'PostImage' object has no attribute 'get'

In my template, I iterate through the **post_image_formset** object, and it iterates 3 times, which is correct, as that particular post has 3 images. But I still get this error. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the part of the template that throws the error. Why does it try to call 'get'? Sounds like a minor error in accessing the variable.

Comment: I updated my question, added my template for the edit page. In the template, I have just tried to access the post_image caption. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you just say "{{ post_image_form }}", or even replace the whole for loop with "{{ post_image_formset }}"?  Does it throw the same error?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates

Comment: Still get the same error. Actually, even when I do print post_image_form.initial in views.py, I get the same error in the console. So, I must have been doing something wrong with the assignment post_image_form.initial = post_image. Can't figure out :S

Answer (score 0):

Your `PostImageForm` is a `ModelForm`. In your edit view you use the `initial` attribute to provide the existing instances. This is not the recommended way and your error may be a symptom of that.

[To provide initial instances a `QuerySet` is used.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)

In your case this would look like this:

```
def post_edit(request, post_slug, template_name="developers/posts/edit.html"):
    post = get_object_or_404(post, slug=post_slug)
    post_images = PostImage.objects.filter(post_id=post.id)

    PostImageFormSet = formset_factory(postImageForm, extra=2)
    formset = PostImageFormSet(queryset=post_images)
```

You also may want to use the recommended way of handling [POST vs. GET requests in form views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view).